# Autogrow WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

You can do the trick with TextBox: when you set AcceptReturn=true, the TextBox will grow as you add new lines of text.

Is it possible to do the same to RichTextBox?

I'm doing this in WPF

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268375/richtextbox-equivalent-of-textbox-acceptsreturn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268375/richtextbox-equivalent-of-textbox-acceptsreturn)

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate, the OP is wanting to increase the Height of the control as new lines are created. I'm searching for a solution I used.

Comment: @Anurag, the OP is using WPF, not Winforms as the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By default, `RichTextBox` accepts `return` and will grow accordingly. For example, this `RichTextBox` will grow:

```
<Window x:Class="stackoverflow___rich_text_box___accepts_return.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <RichTextBox/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

You'd have to do this:

```
<RichTextBox AcceptsReturn="False"/>
```

to get it *not* to grow.

Comment: Oh.... I've missed Height attribute added by Blend and spent half a day searching for what's wrong. Thanks a lot!